# How to limit the growth of a flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to frame out sections for a future d3 dashboard with the express intent of *not* wanting there to be any scrolling along the sides of the page, and so far I have that functioning correctly ([see here](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~davidlav/EDIS/)).  I also want the red bar to maintain a constant height, and green column to maintain a constant width as the viewport resizes (which it currently does).

I also want each of the colored boxes to scroll internally as they fill with content (table rows of data) so as not to affect the size of the interface as a whole.  But when I add elements to the news feed div, for example, on the right hand side, it grows to accommodate them (not what I want).  Here's a [runnable gist](https://gist.run/?id=71424e1a7b38a5c2fe6484c8e6f764ae) showing the problem.

Rather than the example stack of `<p>` tags modifying the height of the **entire** parent div `<div id="under-splash-banner">` (notice how the other blue boxes all stretch as a result) and creating a vertical scroll bar along the **entire** height of the right side, I want the green news feed div to scroll internally to reveal all its content rather than growing beyond its default, empty size (and thereby forcing the entire window to scroll).

Does this have something to do with the fact that I have no max height specified for it or its parent?  If so, how would I do that and retain the responsive nature of the layout?

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto';
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';

/* line 4, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* line 7, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
/* line 10, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
/* line 17, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

.place-holder {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 18pt;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/* line 23, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#splash-banner {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* line 27, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#under-splash-banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100vw;
}
/* line 33, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#news-feed {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
/* line 37, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#resizable-panels {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
/* line 42, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#patient-info {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
/* line 46, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#order-history {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}
/* line 50, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#health-status {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
/* line 54, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#to-do {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
/* line 58, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#timeline {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
/* line 63, D:/Webstorm Projects/EDIS/css/style.sass */

#timeline-svg {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="under-splash-banner">
  <div class="place-holder" id="news-feed">News Feed</div>
  <div id="resizable-panels">
    <div id="patient-info">
      <div class="place-holder" id="order-history">Order History</div>
      <div class="place-holder" id="health-status">Health Status</div>
      <div class="place-holder" id="to-do">To Do</div>
    </div>
    <div id="timeline" style="background: lightgray;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I played around with your current working page and these changes seem to do what you're after:

```
#news-feed {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! At first I couldn't get your changes to work, but then I tried it in Chrome (instead of Firefox) and it functioned perfectly.  Issue must be with Firefox then.

Comment: Do you have any idea what's causing Firefox to render it completely different from Chrome?

Comment: Flexbox still has some bugs in various implementations, including Firefox's - this might be one of those. You can work around it by setting a height on the `#news-feed` div - if the height of the 'splash bar' across the top is 100px, you can make `#news-feed` the right height with `height: calc(100vh - 100px)`. 1 browser window's height, minus the splash bar.